# Vue Router with invalid parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning how to use vue router and I can't understand how to do something.

I have a route with this path: '/entry/:id/'.
So, I want a detail page.

I loop through every entry with v-for, obviously, get the id from that entry and then send it as param to router-link, like so:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'entry-detail', params: {id: entry.id} }">
```

When the link is accessed, I get the this.$route.params.id and I'm able to make a get request to API in order to get that specific entry.
The problem is that when I access the entry-detail page with an invalid id that doesn't exist (e.g. /entry/invalid_id/), it gets me the layout without the data, fair enough, but how can I manage to redirect from that page or displaying 404 template instead of just having a blank filled page?

Sorry for my grammar mistakes, by the way.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ajax response returns an error code, then you should be able to catch this and handle it in your response, I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) here:

```
axios.get('/api/results/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
  // success, set the model variables
}).catch(error => {
  // Nope, let's check what the error was
   if(error.response.status === 404){    
     // redirect user   
     this.$router.push('/notFound')
   }
})
```

If you don't get an error response you can just redirect when data is null:

```
axios.get('/api/results/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
  // success, set the model variables
  if(response.data == null){
    this.$router.push('/notFound')
  }
  // success, set the model variables
}).catch(error => {
  // Handle errors
})
```

Comment: I use axios too. Thanks for the answer, I think this solved my problem.